# How to set the background color in amp-story?

Tags: background-color, amp-story

The best practices guideline recommends setting the background color but does not give an example of how to do so in amp-story.

Can you please provide an example for users to follow?

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp_story_best_practices[best practices - set background color](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp_story_best_practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the background-color with styles, add class or style attribute to amp-story or amp-story-page tag.

Comment: It's best to set the background color on the `amp-story-page`.  You can just use e.g. `<style amp-custom>amp-story-page { background-color: red }</style>`